# Triangulation of projective plane

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I would like to have the triangulations of a real projective plane with large vertex sets. The one that is available is with 6 vertices. How can one triangulate the projective plane with more vertices, say more than 15 vertices?

Answer (score 1):

Just take a triangulation with fewer vertices and subdivide. For example you can make two neighboring triangles into four by introducing the "other diagonal" of that quadrangle. This introduces exactly one new vertex.

Comment: Thanks! Are all triangulations of the projective plane obtained from a smaller one by your method?

Comment: Look at http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0095895682900417 : all trianglations can be generated by such construction and its dual construction from either the 6-vertex-triangulation or a certain 7-vertex-triangulation.

Comment: Great! Thanks. I checked that paper and in figure 3 the two irreducible triangulations are displayed. I wonder how to label the vertices in order to have a triangulation. The left hand side picture should be isomorphic to https://i.stack.imgur.com/91XRZ.png.

Comment: Answer of my last question: the triangulation of the projective plane given in the above paper (with 6 vertices) illustrates the complement of the triangulation given in https://i.stack.imgur.com/91XRZ.png.